# How to maintain a light-weight Git repo with truncated history

Tags: git

Given a repo **all-history.git** containing millions of commits, how would one create and maintain a second, lighter-weight repo **last-year-of-history.git** that developers use in their day-to-day operations?  Both repos would have all the recent activity performed by developers (commits/branches/tags/etc) but the lighter-weight repo would only contain the last year of this activity.

I came up with a method which truncates commits in **last-year-of-history.git** and deletes old tags and branches, but the process I used to push changes developers are making from **last-year-of-history.git** to **all-history.git** is pushing the truncated commit and breaking file histories, rendering the intent of **all-history.git** useless.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some other reason that you didn't state for wanting to do this, a better solution is to use **shallow clones**.

Developers (and your CI process) can perform shallow clones and pull back as much or as little of the history as they want, then work against the repository normally.

They can clone with 
`--depth 10` to only clone the last 10 commits in the repo

Or, they can use 
`--shallow-since=<date>`

which seems more in line with what you're doing right now: They can clone all the commits starting at a given date.

Comment: Shallow clones did provide a huge benefit, but I went further and found that working in a repo which simply had less commits provided another order of magnitude performance benefit.